# How can i rename directory in Laravel5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How can I rename directory on public , In my controller ?
I read Laravel document but File class doesn't have rename .

```
File::move();
```

I just need rename , I cant move my files to an other Folder

Comment: move and rename are the same in this context.

Comment: users wrote answer and they are true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use PHP's build-in function "rename" :-) http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Answer (score 7):

Laravel Docs

The move method may be used to rename or move an existing file to a new location:

```
 Storage::move('hodor/file1.jpg', 'holdthedoor/file2.jpg');
```

this way, you can rename without moving

```
Storage::move('hodor/oldfile-name.jpg', 'hodor/newfile-name.jpg'); // keep the same folder to just rename 

Storage::move('hodor/old-folder-name', 'hodor/new-cool-folder-name'); //rename folder
```

Comment: Files are not in storage .

Comment: can u explain? if you have them somewhere else(public folder), you need to change (or create a new) Disk and use it

Answer (score 0):

in your Controller called:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

And use tow Methods of Filesystem in public function :

01#

```
$copyDirectory = File::copyDirectory(string $directory, string $destination);
```

"Copy a directory from one location to another."

02#

```
$deleteDirectory = File::deleteDirectories(string $directory);
```

"Remove all of the directories within a given directory."

OR

Use This :

```
rename ( string $oldname , string $newname , resource $context = ? ) : bool
```

Answer (score -1):

use this with same directory

```
$success = File::copyDirectory($sourceDir, $destinationDir);
```